# jQuery scroll top function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset, scrolltop

So here is my code and I have this error and I don't understand why. I need some help here... I don't know why is this happening : `Property does not exist on type '.js--section-plan'.ts(2339)` when i hover on the `offset()` in vscode

```
$('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function() 
  { $('html, body).animate({scrollTop:. 
    ('.js--section- 
    plan').offset().top},1000) });
```

Comment: Does your code actually say `$('html, body)` instead of `$('html, body')`, or is that just a typo on the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should put a quote mark on the end of the body, just right before the paranthesis. Also that period isn't needed after the colon.

```
$('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function() { 
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.js--section- plan').offset().top
  }, 1000); 
});
```

Comment: Change `('.js--section- plan')` to `$('.js--section- plan')`

Comment: . It's a typo. It's supposed to be there.

Comment: It's the offset cos when i hover on it in vscode it brings out the Property does not exist on type '.js--section-plan'.ts(233

Answer (score 1):

There are some minor typos in your script. Do not forget to use $-sign.

```
$('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function() { 
    $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('.js--section-plan').offset().top
 }, 1000); 
});
```

Comment: I used it. It was a typo